# How do I resolve a foreign key mismatch error?

Tags: sqlite

I tried inserting values into my 'JobTypes' table but I keep getting a foreign key mismatch error. I think I've made an error with my foreign keys but I can't quite figure out where exactly as I'm quite new at this, can anyone help me out?

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE Projects ( 
Proj_ID INTEGER, 
Proj_name TEXT, 
PRIMARY KEY (Proj_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Employees ( 
Emp_ID INTEGER,
Proj_ID INTEGER,
Emp_fname TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY(Emp_ID, Proj_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(Proj_ID) REFERENCES Projects(Proj_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE HourRates ( 
Job_type TEXT,
Hour_rate TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY(Job_type)
);

CREATE TABLE JobTypes ( 
Emp_ID INTEGER,
Job_type TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY(Emp_ID)
FOREIGN KEY (Emp_ID) REFERENCES Employees(Emp_ID)
FOREIGN KEY (Job_type) REFERENCES HourRates(Job_type)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Every FKEY target must be either a primary key or have an explicit unique index defined. Employees(Emp_ID) does not have a unique constraint or index. If this column is unique, you need to add a unique constraint or define a simple PKEY. Otherwise, you will not be able insert any data into the JobTypes table. The error message generated is confusing, and SQLite should at least issue some kind of warning when you create the JobTypes table, but this is not how it works, perhaps, due to the need for backward compatibility. Anyhow, my guess is that your Employees table actually needs to be split into Employees & Employees_Projects (many-to-many) tables.